# how to update google map center when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been able to put a marker at the center of the google map using the below code and clicking on the marker show an infowindow about the center coordinates. But when i scroll the map and then click on the marker, it show the same coordinates. How to update so that when i zoom/scroll/pan the map it will show the updated center?
Help please.

```
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);
    $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
         //do something onclick
        .click(function(){
           var that=$(this);
           if(!that.data('win')){
            that.data('win',new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:
                           myGeoCode(map.getCenter())
                                                       }));
            that.data('win').bindTo('position',map,'center');
           }
           that.data('win').open(map);
        });
    }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function myGeoCode(latlng){
      return 'Your Coor is ' + latlng;
    }
```

Comment: I dont really understand the "scroll the map" and then "Click on the marker". if the marker is on the same position, the value is not supposed to change even if you zoom. Can you be more specific ? also, jsfiddle would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, i guess i wasn't very clear with the question,..scroll the map = panning the map. Actually i want a marker to be at the center of the map and remain at the center of the map even if the user pans the map/ zoom in/zoom out. And when the user clicks on the marker an infowindow will pop up showing the co-ordinates on which the marker is on.

Answer (score 0):

What are the bindto methods/etc? Does not look like you are using a standard marker...anyways you can use the idle event to update the marker/infowindow

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
   // assign map.getCenter() to InfoWindow reference
})
```

Comment: i tried using standard marker, but then i have remove the marker and place it back at the center when the user pans the map which causes flickering of the marker.

Comment: The only work around i can think of is to remove the marker when the user is panning/zooming and when the user is idle, put the marker back on the map which works. but i couldn't figure out how to update the marker so that it shows the updated center of the map when clicked on.